# Transposing a 2D array

Tags: beginner, ruby, matrix

Would you have any suggestions for improvements for the code below?

```
def my_transpose(arr)
  # number of rows
  m = arr.count

  #number of columns
  n = arr[0].count

  transposed_arr = Array.new(n) { Array.new(m) }

  # loop through the rows
  arr.each_with_index do |row, index1|

    # loop through the colons of one row
    row.each_with_index do |num, index2|

      # swap indexes to transpose the initial array
      transposed_arr[index2][index1] = num
      p transposed_arr
    end
  end
  transposed_arr
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already mentioned, Ruby's `Array` comes with a built-in `#transpose` method.

But, for the purposes of an exercise, there are multiple ways to do the same thing.

For instance, one way (which only works for square matrices!) is to use `#map`:

```
def my_transpose(arr)
  arr.each_with_index.map do |_, index|
    arr.map { |row| row[index] }
  end
end
```

Or you can use `reduce` (this will work for rectangular matrices):

```
def my_transpose(arr)
  arr.reduce([]) do |transposed, row|
    row.each_with_index do |value, col|
      transposed[col] ||= []
      transposed[col] << value
    end
    transposed
  end
end
```

Or do basially the same thing, just using `each_with_object`:

```
def my_transpose(arr)
  arr.each_with_object([]) do |row, transposed|
    row.each_with_index do |value, col|
      transposed[col] ||= []
      transposed[col] << value
    end
  end
end
```

But keeping more of your code, you could use `Array#new` as your loop, since it accepts a block.

For instance:

```
def my_transpose(arr)
  rows = arr.count
  cols = arr.first.count
  Array.new(cols) do |col|
    Array.new(rows) do |row|
      arr[row][col]
    end
  end
end
```

Of course, you'll want to check a few things. Firstly, whether there are any rows in the matrix at all (if not, the `arr[0].count` will fail), and whether the matrix is actually rectangular:

```
def my_transpose(arr)
  return [] if arr.empty?

  rows = arr.count
  cols = arr.first.count

  raise ArgumentError unless arr.all? { |row| row.count == cols }

  Array.new(cols) do |col|
    Array.new(rows) do |row|
      arr[row][col]
    end
  end
end
```

There are yet more ways to do things, but again: It's already built in as `arr.transpose`.

Comment: Thanks, looking at different ways to do things really help get a grasp of the language. Thx again!

Answer (score 6):

[Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) is a built-in Ruby method. Try instead:

```
p transposed_arr = arr.transpose
```

Comment: Just to match what the original poster's code does.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before transpose is a built-in which is fine if don't have space constraint O(N), but if you need O(1) you can do in-place transpose:

```
def transpose(matrix)
  size = matrix[0].size # assumes square matrix
  (0..(size - 2 )).to_a.each do |y|
    (y..(size - 1)).to_a.each do |x|
      matrix[y][x], matrix[x][y] = matrix[x][y], matrix[y][x]
    end
  end
end
```

More about this on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition)